# Search files Google Drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a folder A with folderID. Also, there are some folders in this folder A. How can I search for files in Google Drive API just in particular folder? I use parameter q = 'parentID' in parents. But in response I find files from my subsidiary folders. What should I do to list files located in only my folder A?

Comment: `in response I find files from my subsidiary folders` are you sure you are getting that? If you're using `Files: list` with `q = 'parentID' in parents` you should be getting only files contained in folder A (including folders), **not files contained in folders contained in folder A**. Can you share the call you're making?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I get only files in ma particular folder.

Comment: All right. In such case, this issue is solved?

Comment: YES! And, maybe, do you know how can i search for files located on my Google Drive? For example: on my main page I have 3 folders: folderA, folderB, folderC. In folderA I have folder1. https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%20%3D%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27
What should I add to my request, to get in response only folders from main page: folderA, folderB, folderC. Without folder1

Comment: If you don't want to get "subfolders", you don't need to do anything. A `Files: list` with `q = 'parentID' in parents` will only get the **direct** children from the `parentID` folder. No folders and no files contained in one of the child folders will show up.

Comment: ok, i understood
Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome Igor. Now that your issue is solved, I posted an answer explaining this for documentation purposes. Please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This would be useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and specify that you only want files which have a certain parent folder (via `q = 'parentID' in parents`), you will only get the files which are "**direct children**" of this parent folder, and **not** files contained in one of these children.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Can you please give an example for HTTP/REST? I have tried `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q: name contains 'note'` but it's not working

Comment: @TanvirAhmed Try `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%20contains%20%27note%27`